# AdminOrderController enable(?)

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to edit a little bit the admin of the DemoSite.

I manage successfully to add a new tab at the side bar with the link "/order" (via a database import).

So broadleaf successfully directs me to /admin/order.There I get a

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: order
```

error

So I want to use the AdminOrderController found in broadleaf-admin-module (which from the description seems to handle the "/order" link).

My question is how to "enable" this controller? Maybe is a noob question cause I am getting confused on how broadleaf deploys all its resources.

So any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you provide the SQL that you used and more of the stacktrace?

Comment: @mouse_8b hey aparrently I moved a little bit and this is the error I am getting now:https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite/issues/44   .However as I couldn't figure it out I created my own custom controller